# Doctrine and unique entities in many-to-many, possible?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two classes `A` and `B` in many to many relation.

the class A looks like this:

```
/** @ORM\Entity **/
class A {
    /** @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="B", cascade={"all"}) **/
    public $x;
}
```

the doctrine will create a glue `A_B` table with columns `AId` and `BId`.

Is it possible to make the `BId` column unique, ie. there will no `B` entity in for two `A` entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is a unidirectional One-to-Many association. To set it up, you need to use the [`JoinTable`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-jointable) annotation to enforce the one-to-many cardinality as explained [in this section of the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table).

With your `A` and `B` entities, it would be something like:

```php
/** @ORM\Entity **/
class A 
{
    /* ... other attributes ... */

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="B")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(unique=true, onDelete="CASCADE")})
     */    
    public $bs;
}
```

I just kept the `unique` option that applies on the `b_id` column as other options such as column and table names are automatically generated for you anyway. I added `onDelete="CASCADE"` as it should be the default behaviour you would want in an association table.

With this association, doctrine will output the following schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE a_b (a_id INT NOT NULL, b_id INT NOT NULL, INDEX IDX_28CB39EA3BDE5358 (a_id), UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_28CB39EA296BFCB6 (b_id), PRIMARY KEY(a_id, b_id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE a_b ADD CONSTRAINT FK_28CB39EA3BDE5358 FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES a (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE a_b ADD CONSTRAINT FK_28CB39EA296BFCB6 FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES b (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

---

On a side note, if it does not matter that B owns the association, simply having a bidirectional [`OneToMany`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) association owned by B and inversed in A would do as it would add a foreign key on `B`'s table referring to A, thus enforcing the right cardinality as well.

Comment: I am using the `cascade` for cascading persist(), flush(), etc. operations. Is the database `onCascade` usefull for something if the data are managed solely by Doctrine (with the `cascade={"all"}`)?

Comment: Adding database level cascade operations ensure that your database always stays in a proper state and knows how to act in some cases. For example, without the additional `onDelete` here, removing a `B` entity referred by an `A` entity would trigger a foreign key constraint error. That's why by default join tables generated by doctrine have this onDelete option and why I added it in the `JoinColumn`. [See also this section about cascade operations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations)

Answer (score 0):

So you want:

One B entity to relate to only one A entity, but one A entity can relate to many different B entities.

This can be done by making the relation to OneToMany from A to B:

```
class A { 
      /**     
       * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="B", mappedBy="a", cascade={"all"}) 
      **/ 
      public $x;
  }
```

and in entity B:

```
class B { 
      /**     
       * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="A", inversedBy="x") 
      **/ 
      public $a;
  }
```

This way, each B entity will be "unique", as a foreigh key relation to A 's id is created on B entity 's table.

Do not be confused by the name "OneToMany", 2 B entities cannot be shared between 2 A entities, that would be a ManyToMany. Each B entity will belong to only one A entity.

Comment: This does not generate the "N:N table" at all.